Responsive Image With Text at Any Screen Width
I have an image with text and need to make sure the text in the image displays at any screen width for small hand held mobiles but also large desktops.
The problem i have is the image becomes cutoff on smaller screens and the gap around the image changes at different screen widths.
Is it possible to make sure the image resizes at any screen width and always shows the entire image as well as maintaining the same padding/space before and after the image?
It should always display full width of screen.
Here is my HTML and CSS. I am open to using jQuery if needed.


.nav-primary {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 32px;
}

.custom-header {
      background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/SwSktxv/desktop.png');
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      height: 250px;
}
<nav class="nav-primary"></nav>

<header class="custom-header"></header>




I am not clear on the requirement - how can an image that has to be full width of any viewport always have room vertically to fit into that viewport? Remember viewport aspect ratios can be anything, as can image's aspect ratios.

I don't see how it could ever get "cut off", when you are using background-size: contain. "and the gap around the image changes at different screen widths" - of course, because of background-size: contain - the image scales proportionally, so that it can be fully shown in all situations; and that of course leaves different "gaps" within the fixed-height div itself.

Why are you using this as a background image to begin with? Especially when apparently it contains relevant(?) text, it should rather be embedded via an img element (so that you can place the text content into the alt attribute as proper alternative for users who won't be able to read it from the image itself.)

@CBroe Thank You. I've printed the output busing PHP with an image tag now which works much better except the fixed nav bar covers the top part of the image on desktops because of position:fixed;. Any CSS help with this would be appreciated.

If your navbar covers the image, before even any scrolling happens, because the image is right at the top - then you need to move it further down, for example by giving body a corresponding padding-top or something like that.

You can ensure your image displays fully and consistently across different screen sizes by using background-size: cover; and percentage-based padding for consistent spacing around the image.
.custom-header {
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/SwSktxv/desktop.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 250px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
    padding: 10% 0; /* Adjust the percentage values for top and bottom padding */
}

This will make the image cover the entire header area while maintaining its aspect ratio, and the percentage-based padding ensures consistent spacing around the image regardless of screen width.
I don't know if this will solve your problem or not but I hope this will be useful to you. 

The requirement is that all the image be visible. cover does not do this.

position:fixed; is the problem on desktops only as its removed on mobiles
